# Locked out when attempting a migratoin

Tags: staging

I am porting my site over to a staging server for experimentation using the duplicator plugin.  Been getting a lot of strange artifacts along the way, including the password no longer working.  The wp-config file was changed, so I'm thinking that this has futzed up a lot of the security keys, etc.

I attempted a pw reset and the key for that is invalid as well, failing on multiple attempts.  I'm at a loss here, how do I log in?  I have access to the database and all the files on the server and I am not particularly worried about meddling as this is a staging server.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the keys and salts from the production site?

Try updating the password with WP-CLI?

Comment: This is on a shared hosting server, I'll have to see if I can get ssh access and will try this later, thanks!

Comment: You don't have access to the wp-config on the live site? That's where the keys are.

Comment: I do have access to wp-config, but I don't know what the previous keys were.  I think duplicator over wrote, something got mixed up and I'm not sure what or where

Comment: If you can FTP you can probably SSH. just try `ssh username@domain.com` - password should be the same. Worth a try.